# Not able to download Scipy package for Python

Tags: python-2.7, scipy, pip, install.packages

I initially downloaded Python, later I installed pip and when I started downloading numpy, pandas all where installed correctly but I have problem in downloading the scipy, below I have attached my screenshot of the error appeared on my cmd.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Consider using Anaconda which includes a lot of batteries: https://www.continuum.io/downloads

Comment: Whenever you have text information to present, please copy it into your question as text, using the available formatting tool. Text is much easier to work with than images, since it is compatible with clipboards, search engines and screen readers.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, solved it by installing it from the binaries that you can find [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#scipy) just download the `.whl` file and execute `pip install file.whl`

**Install [numpy+mkl](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy) before installing scipy.**

Comment: Thanks alot, the solution given by you really worked.

Comment: you welcome, if it works can you accept my answer? @hiteshsaai

Comment: how to do that ?